# Elasticsearch Curator not to delete the last index while deleting indices by filtertypes

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-curator

Using Elasticsearch 5.1 and Curator version is 4.3 in Centos 7

I am having some indices in elasticsearch whose naming format is sample.data.YYYY_MM_DD , sample.file.YYYY_MM_DD
For example:-

```
sample.data.2019_07_22
sample.data.2019_07_23
sample.data.2019_07_25
sample.data.2019_07_26
sample.data.2019_07_28
sample.file.2019_07_21
sample.file.2019_07_25
sample.file.2019_07_26
sample.file.2019_07_29
```

I have used to run the action file by using the below command in Linux.

**curator --config /root/config.yml /root/action_file.yml**

I wanted to delete all indices except the recent index which is have created newer [ sample.data.2019_07_28, sample.file.2019_07_29 ]

**This is the which i tried :-**

```
  ---
  actions:
   1:
    action: delete_indices
    description: "Delete indices older than 3 days (based on index name), for workflow- prefixed indices. Ignore the error if the filter does not result in an actionable list of indices (ignore_empty_list) and exit cleanly."
    filters:
      - 
        exclude: ~
        filtertype: pattern
        kind: prefix
        value: sample.*.
      - 
        direction: older
        exclude: ~
        filtertype: age
        source: name
        timestring: "%Y%m%d"
        unit: days
        unit_count: 3
    options:
      continue_if_exception: false
      disable_action: false
      ignore_empty_list: true
      timeout_override: ~
```

Its deleting overall indices even though i have used the below function also,

```
- filtertype: count
  count: 4
```

Expected output be like :-

```
sample.data.2019_07_28
sample.file.2019_07_29
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change your `timestring` from `timestring: "%Y%m%d"` to `timestring: "%Y_%m_%d"`. When I test with a dry run I get:

```
2019-08-02 15:02:47,493 INFO      Preparing Action ID: 1, "delete_indices"
2019-08-02 15:02:47,513 INFO      Trying Action ID: 1, "delete_indices": Delete indices older than 3 days (based on index name), for workflow- prefixed indices. Ignore the error if the filter does not result in an actionable list of indices (ignore_empty_list) and exit cleanly.
2019-08-02 15:02:48,709 INFO      DRY-RUN MODE.  No changes will be made.
2019-08-02 15:02:48,709 INFO      (CLOSED) indices may be shown that may not be acted on by action "delete_indices".
2019-08-02 15:02:48,709 INFO      DRY-RUN: delete_indices: sample.file.2019_07_26 with arguments: {}
2019-08-02 15:02:48,709 INFO      DRY-RUN: delete_indices: sample.file.2019_07_27 with arguments: {}
2019-08-02 15:02:48,710 INFO      DRY-RUN: delete_indices: sample.file.2019_07_28 with arguments: {}
2019-08-02 15:02:48,710 INFO      DRY-RUN: delete_indices: sample.file.2019_07_29 with arguments: {}
2019-08-02 15:02:48,710 INFO      DRY-RUN: delete_indices: sample.file.2019_07_30 with arguments: {}
2019-08-02 15:02:48,710 INFO      Action ID: 1, "delete_indices" completed.
2019-08-02 15:02:48,710 INFO      Job completed.
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have tried with your time format also. its deleting whole indices. I want new indices should not be deleted. I mean which one is created new.

Comment: Tried with no dry run and removed as expected. I tested with elasticsearch 5.1.1 and curator in version 5.7.6 on windows.

Comment: It will work Rob i know but what i am trying to say is "For Example:  New index not created today and if you are trying to delete 1 day older indices. it will delete all the indices know. I dont want to delete the newer index while running this Curator."

Answer (score 0):

I think you should upgrade to Curator 5.7, which [fully supports Elasticsearch v5](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/5.7/version-compatibility.html), and provides the [count filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/5.7/filtertype_count.html), which can sort indices by age and keep only *n* indices. Using the [exclude flag](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/5.7/fe_exclude.html), you can exclude the most recent index, and then use the regular age filter.